# making a laptop run faster by changing 52 gig hdd

Tags: windows

my friend has a low end laptop thats very slow it has 4 gig of ram 2.2 on cpu but only a 52 gig hdd and not much software installed except for antivirus  I suspect the hdd is the problem, though I know how to fix my own laptop and can reinstall the os I want to make sure of the easiest way to proceed to make his run better its a Lenovo g

Comment: Putting a bigger disk in won't make the computer any faster. Putting a *faster* disk in will likely provide some benefit, though. Replace that old 52 gig spinner with whatever sized sold-state disk you can fit in and you'll probably end up with a faster machine. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your intuition that it's the hard disk is *probably* correct. However, due to the *extremely* low size of that HDD, I'm worried that it might use the IDE interface instead of SATA. If the machine doesn't have any SATA ports, you won't be able to upgrade it to a modern Solid State Disk, and an HDD upgrade wouldn't really be worth your time.
2. Saying that it's a "Lenovo G" is like, if someone asked you "What type of fruit is that?" you answer "Oh, you know, a shaped one". There has to be more you can find out about the model number -- a *lot* more. If you can find the exact model number for us, we could probably provide more detailed information about your upgrade possibilities.
3. The RAM amount isn't *horrible*, but it's pretty low. If you knew exactly what type of RAM it takes (in this case I'm going to guess DDR2-667 or so), you could look for new, compatible RAM to upgrade it. But again you'll hit the limitations of the motherboard when you realize that it probably doesn't support any more than 4 GB of RAM (this is just a wild guess based on the HDD size, which is the most information I could glean from your post about which era this system is from).
4. "2.2 on cpu" is a very non-scientific and un-precise way of saying that the CPU is clocked at 2.2 GHz. But there is a **tremendous** difference in performance between modern CPUs (which might be clocked slightly above 2.2 GHz, but could still be less than 3 GHz) and ancient CPUs from 2005 and older, even if the two CPUs you're comparing have the same clock speed. Newer CPUs can do *more work* within each clock cycle, and have more cores, hyperthreading, a faster system bus and RAM, etc. However, considering how old the rest of the system is, even if you were to dump hundreds of dollars into upgrading this system, the CPU would probably very quickly become a bottleneck on newer operating systems.
5. **Even if** you manage to upgrade the disk to a fast SSD and double the RAM to 8 GB, this system likely can't even run Windows 10 due to the fact that it almost certainly has an ancient Intel Integrated Graphics Processor (IGP) from the early to mid 2000s. These "graphics" processors are so slow and so lacking in features that, often, no driver is available on a modern Windows operating system. Websites today throw so much workload at the GPU with whizzy effects, etc. that you could see very poor performance on the Web even with a fast SSD and upgraded RAM.

In short, unless you have done your **detailed** research into the exact parts of this computer and are very confident that you can upgrade it and that the rest of the system is relatively modern, spending *any* money upgrading it is probably a waste. You'd be much better off spending a few hundred dollars on a new low-end netbook or Chromebook.

Comment: One other option is to use a less resource-intensive OS. There are lots of suitable Linux releases, and this would give you a low-end netboot or Chromebook equivalent without any expenditure at all.